# BeautifulSoup.get_text() ignoring line breaks <br>

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have beautifulsoup4 (4.9.0) installed and am trying to parse some html. Python version 3.7

I'm gathering data from some tables that are split by line breaks `<br>` within the cells e.g.:

```
<td>some text<br>some more text</td>
```

However `.get_text()` seems to ignore the line breaks and print it all int to one line:

```
html = '<td>some text<br>some more text</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')

print(soup)
 >> <td>some text<br/>some more text</td>

print(soup.get_text())
 >> some textsome more text
```

The `<br>` is converted to a `<br/>` but I don't know much HTML so not sure if that's significant.

**Desired outcome**

A list of the strings that are between each line break. I was thinking to use the `.get_text()` method, and then `.split()` the resulting string by the line break character, e.g.:

```
html = '<td>some text<br>some more text</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
strings = soup.get_text().split('?')
  >> ['some text', 'some more text']
```

Anyone know how to get `get_text()` to recognise the line breaks, and what the `?` would need to be? I was thinking maybe to replace the line breaks with an unambiguous character/string that won't be ignored, and split with that. More elegant solutions would be appreciated tho!

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution, as described in the question. Replacing the `<br>` tag with an unambiguous string, then splitting the string using that:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<td>some text<br>some more text</td>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, features='html.parser')
delimiter = '###'                           # unambiguous string
for line_break in soup.findAll('br'):       # loop through line break tags
    line_break.replaceWith(delimiter)       # replace br tags with delimiter
strings = soup.get_text().split(delimiter)  # get list of strings
  >> ['some text', 'some more text']        # output
```